# Stored procedure not working properly via EXECUTE but works perfectly as a giant SQL query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a stored procedure that runs fine when I copy the whole thing as a SQL query and run it, but that exact same procedure with the same parameters using an EXECUTE command ouputs the WRONG data!

```
EXECUTE qrm_pulsar_sandbox.[dbo].[sp_PL_Hedge] @CurrentDate = '12/17/2014', @PriorDate = '12/16/2014'
```

The following is the first part of the stored procedure as a query:

```
DECLARE @CURRENTDATE AS DATE
DECLARE @PRIORDATE AS DATE
SET @CURRENTDATE = '12/17/2014'
SET @PRIORDATE = '12/16/2014'

---------------Erroneous trades--------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ErrorTrades') is not null DROP TABLE #ErrorTrades
Select * 
into #ErrorTrades
from [qrm_pulsar].dbo.PnL_Tradeshistory 
where [CreationDt]<=@CurrentDate and [CreationDt]>= @PriorDate
and [DataVer]='0' and [Loan/Pool/Ticket Number]='1405200007' and [Portfolio ID] ='3'

--------------------all trades-------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#All_Trades') is not null DROP TABLE #All_Trades
select a.*,
 case when a.[OptType] in ('Call','Put') and a.[Instrument name] like '%T-Note%' then 'Options on Futures'
when a.[OptType] in ('Call','Put') then 'MBS Options'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%Treasury%' then 'Bond Futures'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%Eurodollar%' then 'Eurodollar Futures'

when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%FN%' and right(rtrim(a.[Instrument Name]),1)='C' then 'Cash Forwards'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%GN%' and right(rtrim(a.[Instrument Name]),1)='C' then 'Cash Forwards'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%FH%' and right(rtrim(a.[Instrument Name]),1)='C' then 'Cash Forwards'

when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%FN%' then 'MBS Forwards'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%GN%' then 'MBS Forwards'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%FH%' then 'MBS Forwards'
else' Error'end 'Type'

,Case 
when a.[opttype]='Put' and a.[FACE]>0 then 'S' 
when a.[opttype]='Call' and a.[FACE]<0 then 'S' 
when a.[opttype]=''and a.[FACE]<0 then 'S'
else 'B'end 'Sell/Buy'

,case 
when a.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number] in ('1403040003','1401060002','140724TYU1','140724TYU2','140926TYZ5') and a.[Portfolio ID]='7' then 'TRS-MSR'
when a.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number] in ('1401060002','1401070001','1312200001','1402040015','1403040019','140724TYU1','140724TYU2','140926TYZ6') and a.[Portfolio ID]='1' then 'PLS-MSR'
when (rtrim(a.[Management]) <>'MSR' or a.[Management]is null)and a.[Portfolio ID]='1' then 'PLS-Pipeline'
when (rtrim(a.[Management]) <>'MSR' or a.[Management]is null) and a.[Portfolio ID]='7' then 'TRS-Pipeline'
when rtrim(a.[Management]) ='MSR' and a.[Portfolio ID]='1' then 'PLS-MSR'
when rtrim(a.[Management]) ='MSR' and a.[Portfolio ID]='7' then 'TRS-MSR'
when a.[Portfolio ID]='2' then 'TRS-Jumbo Acquisition'
when a.[Portfolio ID]='3' then 'MBS Securities'
when a.[Portfolio ID]='4' then 'Jumbo Securities'
end 'Book'

into #All_Trades
from [qrm_pulsar].dbo.PnL_Tradeshistory a left join #ErrorTrades b 
on a.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number]=b.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number] and a.[Portfolio ID]=b.[Portfolio ID]
where a.[CreationDt]<=@CurrentDate and a.[CreationDt]>= @PriorDate
and a.[DataVer]='0' and b.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number] is null

--Select * from #All_Trades where [Type]='Error'

--------------------all trades no timing restriction to get type------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#All_Trades2') is not null DROP TABLE #All_Trades2
select distinct 
a.[Portfolio ID],
a.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number],
 case when a.[OptType] in ('Call','Put') and a.[Instrument name] like '%T-Note%' then 'Options on Futures'
when a.[OptType] in ('Call','Put') then 'MBS Options'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%Treasury%' then 'Bond Futures'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%Eurodollar%' then 'Eurodollar Futures'

when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%FN%' and right(rtrim(a.[Instrument Name]),1)='C' then 'Cash Forwards'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%GN%' and right(rtrim(a.[Instrument Name]),1)='C' then 'Cash Forwards'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%FH%' and right(rtrim(a.[Instrument Name]),1)='C' then 'Cash Forwards'

when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%FN%' then 'MBS Forwards'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%GN%' then 'MBS Forwards'
when a.[OptType] not in ('Call','Put')and a.[Instrument name] like '%FH%' then 'MBS Forwards'
else' Error'end 'Type'

,Case 
when a.[opttype]='Put' and a.[FACE]>0 then 'S' 
when a.[opttype]='Call' and a.[FACE]<0 then 'S' 
when a.[opttype]=''and a.[FACE]<0 then 'S'
else 'B'end 'Sell/Buy'

,case 
when a.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number] in ('1403040003','1401060002') and a.[Portfolio ID]='7' then 'TRS-MSR'
when a.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number] in ('1401060002','1401070001','1312200001','1402040015','1403040019') and a.[Portfolio ID]='1' then 'PLS-MSR'
when (rtrim(a.[Management]) <>'MSR' or a.[Management]is null)and a.[Portfolio ID]='1' then 'PLS-Pipeline'
when (rtrim(a.[Management]) <>'MSR' or a.[Management]is null) and a.[Portfolio ID]='7' then 'TRS-Pipeline'
when rtrim(a.[Management]) ='MSR' and a.[Portfolio ID]='1' then 'PLS-MSR'
when rtrim(a.[Management]) ='MSR' and a.[Portfolio ID]='7' then 'TRS-MSR'
when a.[Portfolio ID]='2' then 'TRS-Jumbo Acquisition'
when a.[Portfolio ID]='3' then 'MBS Securities'
when a.[Portfolio ID]='4' then 'Jumbo Securities'
end 'Book'

into #All_Trades2
from [qrm_pulsar].dbo.PnL_Tradeshistory a left join #ErrorTrades b 
on a.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number]=b.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number] and a.[Portfolio ID]=b.[Portfolio ID]
where a.[CreationDt]<=@CurrentDate --and a.[CreationDt]>= @PriorDate
and a.[DataVer]='0' and b.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number] is null


--Select * from #All_Trades where [CreationDt]='5/16/2014' and [Loan/Pool/Ticket Number]='140429T038'--and [Portfolio ID]='1'
--Select * from #All_Trades2 where [Loan/Pool/Ticket Number] ='140402TY01'
--------------------all trade settlements-------------------------


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#All_Trades_PO') is not null DROP TABLE #All_Trades_PO
select *
,case 
when ((rtrim([In Ticket Management])<>'MSR'and rtrim([Out Ticket Management])<>'MSR') or ([In Ticket Management]is null and [Out Ticket Management]is null))and [Portfolio ID]='1' then 'PLS-Pipeline'
when ((rtrim([In Ticket Management])<>'MSR'and rtrim([Out Ticket Management])<>'MSR') or ([In Ticket Management]is null and [Out Ticket Management]is null)) and [Portfolio ID]='7' then 'TRS-Pipeline'
when (rtrim([In Ticket Management]) ='MSR' or rtrim([Out Ticket Management]) ='MSR')and [Portfolio ID]='1' then 'PLS-MSR'
when (rtrim([In Ticket Management]) ='MSR' or rtrim([Out Ticket Management]) ='MSR') and [Portfolio ID]='7' then 'TRS-MSR'
when [Portfolio ID]='2' then 'TRS-Jumbo Acquisition'
when [Portfolio ID]='3' then 'MBS Securities'
when [Portfolio ID]='4' then 'Jumbo Securities'
end 'Book'

into #All_Trades_PO
from [qrm_pulsar].dbo.PnL_TradePairoffshistory 
where [CreationDt]=@CurrentDate
and [DataVer]='0'


--Select * from #All_Trades_PO where [In Ticket Number]='1403070007'
--------------------all trade settlements Prior-------------------------


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#All_Trades_PO_Prior') is not null DROP TABLE #All_Trades_PO_Prior
select *
,case 
when ((rtrim([In Ticket Management])<>'MSR'and rtrim([Out Ticket Management])<>'MSR') or ([In Ticket Management]is null and [Out Ticket Management]is null))and [Portfolio ID]='1' then 'PLS-Pipeline'
when ((rtrim([In Ticket Management])<>'MSR'and rtrim([Out Ticket Management])<>'MSR') or ([In Ticket Management]is null and [Out Ticket Management]is null)) and [Portfolio ID]='7' then 'TRS-Pipeline'
when (rtrim([In Ticket Management]) ='MSR' or rtrim([Out Ticket Management]) ='MSR')and [Portfolio ID]='1' then 'PLS-MSR'
when (rtrim([In Ticket Management]) ='MSR' or rtrim([Out Ticket Management]) ='MSR') and [Portfolio ID]='7' then 'TRS-MSR'
when [Portfolio ID]='2' then 'TRS-Jumbo Acquisition'
when [Portfolio ID]='3' then 'MBS Securities'
when [Portfolio ID]='4' then 'Jumbo Securities'
end 'Book'

into #All_Trades_PO_Prior
from [qrm_pulsar].dbo.PnL_TradePairoffshistory 
where [CreationDt]=@PriorDate
and [DataVer]='0'



---------------------Open Position TL---------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OPTL') is not null DROP TABLE #OPTL
select  
[CreationDt],
[DataVer],
[Company],
[Type],
[Sell/Buy],
[OptType],
cast([Loan/Pool/Ticket Number]as varchar)'Ticket #',
[FACE],
abs([FACE])'absFACE',
[Initial Value],
[Current Value],
[Inception Profit/Loss],
[Instrument Name],
[Trade Date],
[Trade Price],
[Counterparty Name],
[Cost],
[Coupon],
[Settle],
[Portfolio ID],
[Management],
[Book],
[Forward Units]
into #OPTL
from #All_Trades a
where 
 [dataver]='0'
and [CreationDt]=@CurrentDate  
Order
by [Loan/Pool/Ticket Number]

--Select * from #OPTL where [Ticket #]in ('1405200007')



---------------------------------All Trades Beg vs. End ---------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TL') is not null DROP TABLE #TL
Select 
a.[CreationDt]
,a.[DataVer]
,a.[Company]
,a.[Type]
,a.[Sell/Buy],
case when a.[CreationDt]=@PriorDate then 'Beg' else 'Additions' end 'Flag'
,case when c.[Ticket #] IS not null then 'Open' else 'Settled' end 'Settled/Open'
,a.[OptType]
,a.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number]'Ticket #'
,(a.[FACE])'Beg Face'
,(c.[FACE])'End Face'
,abs(a.[FACE])'abs Beg Face'
,abs(c.[FACE])'abs End Face'
,a.[Initial Value]'Beg Initial Value'
,a.[Current Value]'Beg Current Value'
,a.[Inception Profit/Loss]'Beg P&L'
,c.[Initial Value]'End Initial Value'
,c.[Current Value]'End Current Value'
,c.[Inception Profit/Loss]'End P&L'
,a.[Instrument Name]
,a.[Trade Date]
,a.[Settle]
,a.[Trade Price]
,a.[Counterparty Name]
,a.[Coupon]
,a.[Portfolio ID],
a.[Management]
,a.[Book]
,a.[Forward Units]
into #TL
from
#All_Trades a left join #OPTL c on a.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number]=c.[Ticket #]and a.[Book]=c.[Book]
where 
( a.[DataVer]='0'
and a.[CreationDt] in (Select MIN(CreationDt)from [qrm_pulsar].dbo.PnL_Tradeshistory b 
where a.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number]=b.[Loan/Pool/Ticket Number]
and a.[Portfolio ID]=b.[Portfolio ID]
and [CreationDt]>= @PriorDate
and [CreationDt]<= @CurrentDate
and [DataVer]='0'))


--select * from #TL where [Ticket #]='140529TYM2' [Type] is null --[Type] is null
--select * from #All_Trades where [Loan/Pool/Ticket Number]='140529TYM2' and [Portfolio ID]='1' order by CreationDt--[Type] is null 
--select * from #OPTL where   [Ticket #]='140307TY01' and [Portfolio ID]='1'--[Type] is null
--select * from #TL where  [Type] is null [Portfolio ID]='3'and [Portfolio ID]='1'




-----------------------------Current Trade Settlement TL--------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#STL') is not null DROP TABLE #STL
select  *
into #STL
from #All_Trades_PO a

where
 [dataver]='0'
and
a.[CreationDt] in (select Max(b.[CreationDt]) from [qrm_pulsar].dbo.PnL_TradePairoffshistory b 
where a.[In Ticket Number]= b.[In Ticket Number]
and a.[Out Ticket Number]= b.[Out Ticket Number]
and a.[Portfolio ID]=b.[Portfolio ID]
and [CreationDt]>@PriorDate
and [CreationDt]<=@CurrentDate
and [dataver]='0')

 --Select * from #STL where [In Ticket Number] ='1404040002'

-----------------------------Trade Settlement AG join on out ticket number--------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#S1') is not null DROP TABLE #S1
Select 
distinct
a.[CreationDt],
a.[DataVer],
a.[Book],
a.[pairoffBuySell]as 'Sell/Buy',
b.[Type],
'Additions' as 'Flag',
'Settled' as 'Settled/Open',
case when a.[OPTION_TYP]='C' then 'Call' 
when a.[OPTION_TYP]='P' then 'Put' 
else ' ' end 'OptType'
```

As well as just an END statement at the end of the stored procedure.

Comment: The output using the EXECUTE command is wrong, as the data does not match the expected results. The output for the same procedure ran as a whole query is completely correct!

Comment: even if I was getting paid to do this, I would be least interested to trying to debug this wall of code, use a smaller example to reproduce the error and with clear goals, Like what you have now and what you expect it to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SP and query are pointed to different databases.
The query is hard coded to point to the qrm_pulsar database, but you are calling the stored procedure in the qrm_pulsar_sandbox database.

Comment: It looks to me like the databases are specified within both using 3-part naming.

Comment: If you use 3 part nameing, and apply the SP in a different database, the SP will still refer to the hard coded DB, not the data of the DB that is in.

Comment: Right. So the results should be identical whether in a query or in the proc.

Comment: not if he is executing the query in a different database. stranger things have been known to happen.

Comment: When he writes `from [qrm_pulsar].dbo.PnL_Tradeshistory`, that is the same table regardless of what database he's connected to.

Comment: my only point is that there is a mismatch between hardcoded db name, and the db that the sp exists in. At a minimum the OP should just verify that he is connected to the right database. We don't know for certain if he is executing the query text in the same DB context so it certainly doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: Jeremy was actually correct, while Rob is technically correct, something strange was going on along the lines of how Jeremy described

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings the stored procedure was created with, such as how NULLs are handled. If you script the database out, you will see these at the top of the script. Then check to see if you have those same settings set when you run the 'Giant SQL Query(tm)'.